# How to find out if a Windows 7 Backup has been completed via a batch file

Tags: backup, windows-7

Is there anyway to have a batch file set up to run on a Windows 7 box and have it check to see if Windows Backup is still running and if not then move the backup?

Comment: Does Windows Backup have the option to run a command when the backup completes? If so, would this not be a better solution?

Comment: That's what I was hoping for, but couldn't anywhere to set that up. I thought about the Task Scheduler, but am not sure where or how to have that run the Backup and then run my script after it completes.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a batch file that runs your backup and when it completes move the backup e.g.

```
windowsbackupcommand

move windowsbackup.file \\somewhere\else\windowsbackup.file
```

Then run that in task scheduler.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but don't know how to run Windows Backup from a batch file. Sorry for being so novice. :P

Comment: @Chris - I believe `wbadmin` is the command you want - Everything you ever wanted to do with Windows Backup from the command line: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754015(WS.10).aspx